# vBulletin Post ID Variable in Plugin

Tags: vbulletin

First off, I'd like to thank anyone who replies in advance--

I am using vBulletin 3.7 (old, I know...), and I am trying to add a plugin that includes the variable $post['postid']. However, it doesn't seem to work. The hook location is 'postbit_display_start'.

I see no need to post more information; the problem is very small, and hopefully very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **postbit_display_complete** as the hook location.
And use this plugin code on your local installation

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($post);echo '</pre>';
```

To see what are within $post.